# Get highest 3 count records from the query in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get a total of all same records from the user table. what I am doing is given below

```
 result = Patient.objects.filter(active=1).values('name').order_by().annotate(Count('name'))
```

Using this I am getting a result like :

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'ankita', 'name_count': 9}, {'name': 'preety', {'count': '8', 'name': "neha'}]>
```

it is returning me the name with count .it is perfect.

How can I get the top 3 results with respect to the location count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **`order_by(...)`** with Python's ***slicing operator*** as

```
result = User.objects.filter(active=1) \
             .values('location__state') \
             .annotate(count_loc=Count('location')) \
             .order_by('-count_loc')[:3]
```

The ***`order_by('-count_loc')`*** gives you the result in decending order and the ***`[:3`]*** gives you the *first 3 entries*.